# Adding/Updating a sql table in VBA

Tags: sql, vba, onclick

I am trying to make it so that Query 1 inserts into 1 of the 3 fields based on whether the task value (grabbed from another table) is selected (true or false check box). This part works.

Query 2 is supposed to update the other 2 fields that are empty to the values in a combo box. This part is not working. Syntactically it seems correct and it isn't crashing. But I just don't think it is reading it in the first place.

All this is supposed to be accomplished via 1 button click.

Query 1:

```
Sub DBInsert_SkillMatrix()
sSQL = "Insert into tblSkillMatrix (Task) Select Task from tblTask WHERE Selected = true"
Set db = CurrentDb
db.Execute (sSQL)
db.Close
End Sub
```

Query 2:

```
Sub DBUpdate_SkillMatrix()
Dim db As DAO.Database
sSQL = "UPDATE tblSkillMatrix SET Skill = '" & Me.cboAST_Skill & "', Requirement = '" & Me.cboAST_Requirement & "' WHERE Skill = ''"
Set db = CurrentDb
Debug.Print (sSQL)
db.Execute (sSQL)
End Sub
```

Comment: I see `WHERE Skill = ''"` at the end of the second query. Is it supposed to be so? Can you show the debug.print (sSQL) ?

Comment: This is the Debug.Print UPDATE tblSkillMatrix SET Skill = 'TCM review and practical experience of tools calibration (basic measurement tools)', Requirement = 'R' WHERE Skill = ''. The " at the end is because the sSQL requires a string value.

Comment: I can see that the problem is that it isn't interpreting the WHERE statement properly, but I'm not sure how else I can tell it to grab the Skills that have a NULL value.

Comment: Try with isnull https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx

Comment: Awesome, this worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in the wrong where clause. It should be with ISNULL. Here is a guidance how to use it - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx